# Unique Key для нескольких столбцов в Entity Framework Core, с авто генерацией значений

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Я использую EF Core и PostgresSql.

```
public class UserPhones
{
    public long Id { get; set;
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; } 
}
```

Таблица в данный момент

```
Id PhoneNumber    UserId
1  "79999999991"  1
2  "79999999991"  2
3  "79999999992"  1
4  "79999999993"  1
5  "79999999993"  2
```

Мне нужно добавить новый столбец ExternalId, так чтобы PhoneNumber и ExternalId были уникальными в зависимости от пользователя

```
public class UserPhones
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long ExternalId { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; } 
}
```

Ожидаемый результат в базе данных:

```
Id PhoneNumber   ExternalId   UserId
1  "79999999991" 1            1
2  "79999999991" 1            2
3  "79999999992" 2            1
4  "79999999993" 3            1
5  "79999999993" 2            2
```

Я пробовал использовать конфигурацию:

```
builder.Property(x => x.ExternalId)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
    .UseNpgsqlIdentityColumn();

builder.HasIndex(x => new {x.ExternalId, x.PhoneNumber})
    .IsUnique();
```

Но получился такой результат:

```
Id PhoneNumber   ExternalId   UserId
1  "79999999991" 1            1
2  "79999999991" 2            2
3  "79999999992" 3            1
4  "79999999993" 4            1
5  "79999999993" 5            2
```